# There is a way to show some content in a Xamarin Page XAML based on a variable?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to write a page that must show some content based on a variable in the binded class.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MyProject.MyClass"
         Title="Beautiful Title">
    <ContentPage.Content>

        //If something true in the MyClass.cs
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Yeeee" />
            <ListView>
                ...
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
        //Else
        <AbsoluteLayout>
            <Label Text="Noooo" />
            <Button>
                ...
            </Button>
        </AbsoluteLayout>

    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

There is a way to do that? My goal is to write a single page instead of two page that differs for few lines of code.

Comment: yes, just set `IsVisible = false;` on the content that you do not want to display

Comment: use data trigger

Comment: @Jason Thank you! It worked perfectly! Shame on me that I didn't think of that simple solution...just set IsVisible="{Binding IsReallyCool}"